# How to make Java Programs communicate on the internet?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, rmi

I am developing a client/server application using Sockets and here is the basic code for the client:

```
Socket sock = new Socket("serversip",9999);

 PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
```

And here's for the server:

```
 ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket(9999);
            Socket sock = ser.accept();
BufferedReader ed = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
```

Whenever, the client and the server applications are on the same network, this works absolutely flawlessly(i use Inet.getLocalhost() and supply the servers's ip to the client manually)

But when they are on different networks(i.e. Internet) and I use:

```
URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                whatismyip.openStream()));
                  String ipp = in.readLine();
```

to obtain the server's public ip address and provide it manually to the client it just won't work.

It always says:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I have used Java RMI before and it too gave the same result i.e. not working on the internet, just working on private network.

So, how am I supposed to establish a connection between remote java programs on the internet, is it even possible?? It makes me wonder then how all these chat applications,etc we use work.

Please help me!! I would be grateful to anyone who reads my problem and at least provides a response. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Are you sure that your server is accessible from the internet, is it public ip? Because what you get from http://checkip.amazonaws.com might be just a public address of your provider's proxy.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply! The server I am currently using is my very own PC(Since I am currently developing) and the ip that checkip.amazonaws.com provides is the same that I obtain when I check on the internet for my IP, so in my opinion it's correct but I may be wrong, Please help me Sir!!

Comment: More than a programming issue, this is a networking issue. The server may be one of many behind a firewall, and the firewall will need to delegate the access to it. The port may be blocked on the firewall. Perhaps you better look for answers on ServerFault.

Comment: But Mr. realskeptic sir please can you tell me is my approach good?? i.e. if I did found the answer to this networking issue on ServerFault and made the port accessible on the internet will the socket technology I am using work, i.e. can the java programs actually communicate on the internet?? what I am doing is it correct??

Comment: @RealSkeptic No, this is not on topic for [sf].

Comment: Are you sure that port 9999 is open to internet traffic for your server? On many networks, ports that are accessible on the local network will not be open to the internet for security reasons. Once you've confirmed that you do have the correct ip for your server (probably via ping), port blocking would be my first suspicion. Working around a port blocking problem depends on how much control you have over the network. Example options: listening on a port known to be open, port forwarding, opening the port to internet traffic.

Comment: Of course Java programs are supposed to communicate over the Internet. If you have a real server, you're supposed to have a permanent public IP, preferably a domain name, and control over the ports. But you are also supposed to understand how to set this all up. You will not be doing it with `checkip`.

Comment: But Mr. RealSkeptic whenever I check on the internet what's my ip, it's the same as what is provided by checkip?? I may be wrong, but I think the IP address I am using is correct, is it not?? Please correct me if I am wrong??

Comment: Mr. Brian Swift, thank you for your reply! Sir I am currently using my own PC as the server for the project development and I don't know how to check whether the port is open to Internet traffic or not, I am really amateur at this, I have recently learned all this and I am not sure what to do next?? Please help me what approach am I supposed to follow??

Answer (score 0):

`checkip` returns the server's public IP, but it is likely that the server is behind a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). In that case the server is part of a [Local Area Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) and it has a local IP address (such as 192.168.1.2). You will have to map the port 9999 on the NAT device (e.g. the router provided by the ISP in a residential connection) to the same port on the server at 192.168.1.2. Some ISP manage the NAT itself and don't allow them to be configured by the users.

Another point to consider are [firewalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)). There is a (software) firewall running on the server itself (such as the Windows Firewall, or iptables in Linux), as well as there may be a firewall on the client side that is blocking the outgoing connections to port 9999. In the case of residential connections, the ISP may also be blocking traffic on that port. In corporate networks, outgoing connections to arbitrary ports are sometimes blocked too.

Comment: Mr. Javier, I understand what your point is but then if I deploy this application on a real server will this work??(I am currently using my own PC as a server, since I am developing at the moment). I think the real server won't face all these problems right?? Is my approach good i.e. will the socket technology I have been using work?? Or else i'll stop wasting my time on this project.Please reply!!

Comment: If it works with the client and server in the same network, the implementation is right, and it will work when deployed to a server with a public IP. However, some clients could be forbidden to connect to port 9999 of your server.